# How to interpret $A A' = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-analysis

(I edited the question to be more relevant and informative/specific. Hope it's better). I'm unsure of how to interpret
$$A A' = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
where A and A' are 2x2 complex singular matrices defined as
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{pmatrix}$$
and
$$A' = \begin{pmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{pmatrix}$$
Where $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{C}$. What would this imply in terms of linear algebra. Are they orthogonal to each other? What would the nature of A be for this condition to be true?.
Also, if anyone knows what field/theory these matrices are used in?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Is $A$ a real matrix or a complex matrix?

Comment: At least one of the matrices is singular. But since their determinants are equal, both are singular.

Comment: If $A$ is real then $A=0$ because  rank$(AA^T)=$rank$(A)$

Comment: Clifford matrix?

Comment: It's a complex matrix since $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{C}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2=0$$
$$b=\pm ia$$
$$d=\pm ic$$
$$ac+bd=0$$
If take same sign in $\pm$, then this always hold.

Case 1:
$$\left(\matrix{a&ia\\c&ic}\right)$$

Case 2:
$$\left(\matrix{a&-ia\\c&-ic}\right)$$
If take opposite sign in $\pm$, then $ac=0$

Case 3:
$$\left(\matrix{0&0\\c&\pm ic}\right)$$

Case 4:
$$\left(\matrix{a&\pm ia\\0&0}\right)$$

Case 3 and 4 are aleady included in 1 and 2.

Hence the answer is

$$\left(\matrix{a&\pm ia\\c&\pm ic}\right)=\left(\matrix{a\\c}\right)\left(\matrix{1 & \pm i}\right)$$

Comment: Ah yes, all the examples I have follow this. Thank you! Do you know what field/theory these matrices are used? or if they are useful at all?

Comment: Sorry that I don't know

Comment: thanks for the answer anyway!